# FOSRestBundle - "Undefined offset: 0" in vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener.php line 99

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a problem most probably with FOSRestBundle configuration.
I have this message:

```
"Undefined offset: 0" in ...\vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\EventListener\ViewResponseListener.php line 99
```

This occurs when I return something catched by the ViewResponseListener for example in this piece of code :

```
 /**
  * Show an ingredient
  * @FOSRest\Get(path="/api/ingredient/{ingredient}", requirements={ "ingredient"="\d+" }, name="show_ingredient")
  * @FOSRest\View(StatusCode = 200, populateDefaultVars=false, serializerGroups={ "Show", "creator" : { "Short" }, "types" : {"Short"} })
  *
  * @param Ingredient $ingredient
  * @return Ingredient|View|Response
  */
 public function showIngredientAction(Ingredient $ingredient) {
     return $ingredient;
 }
```

This is my FOSRest config :

```
 fos_rest:
  routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format: false
  body_listener: true
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - {  path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
  param_fetcher_listener: true
  access_denied_listener:
    json: true
  view:
    view_response_listener: true
    formats:
      json: true
  body_converter:
    enabled: true
```

**EDIT**

My composer:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        ...
        "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "^1.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.5",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have some news. I checked on an other PC where the app works. It seems that we have some differencies in the vendor files of framework-extra-bundle.

```
namespace Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration;
/**
* The Template class handles the Template annotation parts.
*
* @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
* @Annotation
 */
class Template extends ConfigurationAnnotation
{

         ....

        ----------------- After --------------------

        /**
         * The controller (+action) this annotation is set to.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        private $owner = [];

       ----------------- Before --------------------
        /**
         * The controller (+action) this annotation is set to.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        private $owner;
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question with your symfony version and FOSRestBundle version (composer info ...)

Comment: Thank you for your time :) I've added my composer config.

Comment: Could you try replace `@FOSRest\View(StatusCode = 200,..` by `@FOSRest\View(statusCode=200, ...)` (without spaces)

Comment: Still no changes. It worked some days ago. I've reinstalled it and since nothing works anymore.